# Convertendo Texto em XML

Tags: android

estou construindo um leitor de rss para um blog onde o arquivo xml me passa as informações de todos os eventos que o blog apresenta (eventos culturais). recuperar o xml e extrair as informações está ok até a parte onde tenho que recuperar os dados dos eventos.
Meio que o Feed me passa tudo em forma de texto com formatação em HTML dentro de uma única tag (tag abaixo)

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<p style="text-align:
```

Como faço pra extrair essas informações de forma organizada? pois quero extrair título, local do evento, descrição e outras informações que estão vindo nesse arquivo. Qual recurso devo usar? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Coloque uma amostra de arquivo inteiro aqui, por favor.

Comment: o arquivo é muito grande mas é esse aqui: http://vomermo.com.br/feed/

Comment: Isso que você está vendo é HTML dentro do seu XML. Isso é usado por certos feeds para tornar o conteúdo mais flexível. Pegue esse HTML e use um parser para extrair o conteúdo dele.

Comment: Certo mas usar um parser mas isso me dá a possibilidade de organizar o conteúdo? por exemplo: crio uma classe chamada Evendo nela tem as propriedades de Descricao e DataLocal, eu posso extrair desse parse essas informações de maneira padronizada? pois digamos que tenho 10 eventos e todos estão descritos em forma de html mas sem marcação nenhuma.

Comment: Alguma estrutura tem que ter nesse HTML, senão não há esperança de fazer nenhuma conversão automática. Uma vez identificada essa estrutura, você vai ter que criar um conversor.